# In publishing, what does the acronym "P/U" or "PU" mean?

Tags: meaning, acronyms, editing, publishing

I have come across this acronym in reference to a project I have been given to revise.  Usually it is in a context such as "PU and modify."

Comment: I had a professor that used to use p/u to mean "pick up," which he explained meant to him reworking the entire passage, paragraph, sentence. It was a broad catch-all essentially saying, "I don't like the way this sounds."

Comment: I thought this would be an easy LMGTFY question, but searching around, nothing is very clear. 'pick up' is the most common, but there's no good explanation, and no links give an explicitly connection to editing.

Comment: @Mitch agreed, which was why I was hesitant to post it as an answer. My experience was purely anecdotal, and I'm not sure it's a standardized editing note.

Comment: @Mitch I also searched and could not find anything definitive (like being listed among other common editing marks), which is why I posted a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[P/U = Pick Up](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=P%2FU).

I believe it is used in the sense of pick this back up and work on it.

Comment: Can you give any further explanation. 'pick up' just doesn't clearly mean to me anything in particular. Is it in a list of common editorial marks?

Comment: @Mitch I have to say I had seen it used in the past, and had to look it up. I don't work in publishing so I can't comment on its commonality. It was fairly meaningless to me, too. (Likely jargon.)

Comment: @Mitch Think [movable type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movable_type).

Comment: I've always understood it as sort of a roundabout way of phrasing what it is you should do to copy that is weak and needs a bit of a pick-me-up, though I guess Elliott's association is much more likely to be historically accurate. It just kind of intuitively makes sense to me that to pick something up means to improve upon it…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that was my understanding, too. But, Elliot makes perfect sense here!

Comment: @Elliot Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

P/U means Pick Up in advertising mark-up. It denotes an element that will be re-used.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Maybe give an example?